# .YAML-tmLanguage strings overlap each other

Tags: regex, string, yaml, sublimetext3

I'm wondering, as I'm making a `.YAML-tmLanguage` file (for Minecraft commands), I'd like to make some code for NBT tags. At the moment it detects all the commands, `@a`, `@r`, `@p`, `@e`, `true`, `false`, and any number.

So I'm wondering, how would I make strings? Currently this is my code:

```
- comment: String (single)
  name: string.quoted.single.mcCmd
  match: \'.*\'
- comment: String (double)
  name: string.quoted.double.mcCmd
  match: \".*\"
```

That works when I only have one of either type (single/double) of string on one line. For example, doing `text:"Hello"` will make `"Hello"` highlighted. It'll also work if I do `text:"Hello",color:'blue'`, but if I try to do `text:"Hello",color:"blue"`, it'll highlight `"Hello",color:"blue"` instead of just `"Hello"` and `"blue"`.

So how would I make the code detect "opening" and "closing" strings?

---

*(Running Sublime Text 3, with AAAPackageDev installed)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\'.*\'`, you can use: `\'[^']*\'` (and similarly for double quotes).

The issue you're having is that the regex `*` operator is "greedy", and will consume as many characters as it can. Therefore, the `.*` is swallowing up everything between the two quotes!

By using `[^']*`, although the operator is still "greedy", it *cannot* go past the closing quotation mark. (In case you don't know the syntax, `[^']` just means "`not '`".)

Comment: That seems to work. :)

Also, I think I can use the `start` and `end` values in my code. But it's also nice to know a pure regex way too. ^_^